# getting multiple results in a cell using helper column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i am trying to categorize text with keywords. such that column b get category name of text in column A using helper column F and G where F is named range "keywords" and G is named range "category".

[image]

i was using this formula from [exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formula/categorize-text-with-keywords) but this only return first result

> =INDEX(category,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keywords,a1)),0))

Google is showing use of textjoin formula but I don't have office 365 subscription.

Comment: I guess [this](https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-words-with-filterxml/) would be of help to you.

Comment: i couldn't get to make it work . i am very basic in excel and just started using formulas etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula solution.

1] For Office 365 and Excel 2019 user, the formula using `Textjoin` function

In `B1`, array formula (Confirm by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter) copied down :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F$1:F$5,A1)),G$1:G$5,""))
```

[image]

2] If you don't have Office 365 Textjoin function, try this longer formula solution for all Excel version.

To create a define name >>

1. Select B1 >> Define Name
2. Name : ArrayResult
3. Refer to :

`=IFERROR(INDEX($G$1:$G$5,N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$5)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$1:$F$5,A1)),ROW($A$1:$A$10))))),"")`

4. Finish

Then,

In `B1` formula copied down :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IFERROR(INDEX(ArrayResult,1),"")&" "&IFERROR(INDEX(ArrayResult,2),"")&" "&IFERROR(INDEX(ArrayResult,3),"")&" "&IFERROR(INDEX(ArrayResult,4),"")&" "&IFERROR(INDEX(ArrayResult,5),""))," ",", ")
```

[image]

Comment: this surely look juicy. will check and report when back to home. thanks mate.

Comment: i checked the lower one and it is working good. any way to avoid comma if suppose category in G is not just vehicle but "small vehicle", I have few entries like that and I am getting results in b like "animal ,small , vehicle"

Comment: edit - got it  =SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IFERROR(INDEX(ArrayResult,1),"")&" , "&IFERROR(INDEX(ArrayResult,2),"")&" , "&IFERROR(INDEX(ArrayResult,3),"")&" , "&IFERROR(INDEX(ArrayResult,4),"")&" , "&IFERROR(INDEX(ArrayResult,5),""))," "," ")